# How to choose from a specific class or property defined the type?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I need to create a system with polymorphic objects.

Each type of object should be handled by a specific handler therefor I need to determine what is the type to handle it correctly.

I'm wondering what would be the best design decision:

- Create an abstract base class something like `ObjectBase`, and then extend to specific
  object, like `CustomObjectA` and `CustomObjectB`
- Create a generic object `GenericObject` and use `$type` property passed to the constructor (the `type` should be immutable).

Note that the object don't differ, just the way they are handled, I mean, there no added property or method or anything in their behavior.

Any feedbacks?

---

**EDIT:**

First solution

```
abstract class ObjectBase {}


class CustomObjectA extends ObjectBase {}

class HandlerManager {
     public function process(ObjectBase $object) {
          if ($object instanceof CustomObjectA) {

              $customObjectAHandler->process($object);
          }
     }
}
```

Second solution

```
class GenericObject {
    protected $type;

    public function __construct($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }
}

class ObjectTypeAHandler {
    public function process(GenericObject) { 
    }

    public function supportsType(GenericObject $object)
    {
        return 'typeA' === $object->getType();
    }
}

   class HandlerManager {
       public function process(GenericObject $object) {
          if ($customObjectAHandler->supportType($object)) {
               $customObjectAHandler->process($object);
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have all handlers share a base class. Have the object create the correct handler with a factory method that is abstract on the base class.

Comment: I don't think that the handler should be set at the Object level, it should be aware of its handler, it is against of lot of rules of OOP (see SOLID) Imho

Comment: I think I wasn't clear: My suggestion is a variant of the abstract factory pattern, only the object plays the part of abstrat factory as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you 1st way. It is not too hard to create 2 objects without body, but if you   want to change their behavior in future - you will have things to get it done.

Comment: There are no reason that behavior change, by the way, the second solution don't forbid you to extend the object to make a custom because the base class will always match